# Uploaded file to Google Docs

Tags: android, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I want to write a sample application for uploading file to Google Doc. Is there any minimum API level for this? Could I add any other libraries for this application? Please help me.. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/mendhak/googledocs-upload-sample) is the example which upload a file to google docs.

This is a sample Android application which uses the google-api-java-client library to demonstrate uploading a file to Google Docs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...Could you please tell me which libraries are use for this application?? Thanks...

Comment: As in there specified in the example, app uses `google-api-java-client` library

Comment: I tried this example with the library... But it doesn't work for me... It shows error like Dx 
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/api/client/auth/RsaSha;  Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Answer (score 2):

The Google Drive SDK documentation includes an Android quickstart tutorial that shows how to write an Android app that uploads photos to Drive:

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android

Comment: i just try quickstart sample i have some error please see this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636659/upload-file-to-google-drive-using-google-play-serivces-libwithout-supporting-ja please help me

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive SDK - Writing your first Drive app in Python :

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJVCKvXtHtE

Documentation :

- https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-python

Uploading files without human interaction, once credentials generated :

- https://github.com/sukujgrg/google_drive

Comment: i just try quickstart sample i have some error please see this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636659/upload-file-to-google-drive-using-google-play-serivces-libwithout-supporting-ja please help me