# Upload file to Google Drive using Google Play serivces lib (without supporting jar files)

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services

I want to upload files/images to Google Drive using Google Play Services lib (without using jar files).

This is possible using Google Drive Android API

[Google Drive Android API](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started)

[I am using the quickstart project from Github:-](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart)

But I am stuck in Google Play Services lib (Due to `DriveApi.DriveContentsResult`):-

```
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.DriveContentsResult;
```

Errors are:-

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.DriveContentsResult;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.MetadataChangeSet;

/**
 * Android Drive Quickstart activity. This activity takes a photo and saves it
 * in Google Drive. The user is prompted with a pre-made dialog which allows
 * them to choose the file location.
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks, 
        OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "android-drive-quickstart";
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR = 2;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 3;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Bitmap mBitmapToSave;

    /**
     * Create a new file and save it to Drive.
     */
    private void saveFileToDrive() {
        // Start by creating a new contents, and setting a callback.
        Log.i(TAG, "Creating new contents.");
        final Bitmap image = mBitmapToSave;

        Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {
                        // If the operation was not successful, we cannot do
                        // anything
                        // and must
                        // fail.
                        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Failed to create new contents.");
                            return;
                        }
                        // Otherwise, we can write our data to the new contents.
                        Log.i(TAG, "New contents created.");
                        // Get an output stream for the contents.
                        OutputStream outputStream = result.getDriveContents()
                                .getOutputStream();
                        // Write the bitmap data from it.
                        ByteArrayOutputStream bitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,
                                bitmapStream);
                        try {
                            outputStream.write(bitmapStream.toByteArray());
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Unable to write file contents.");
                        }
                        // Create the initial metadata - MIME type and title.
                        // Note that the user will be able to change the title
                        // later.
                        MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                .setMimeType("image/jpeg")
                                .setTitle("Android Photo.png").build();
                        // Create an intent for the file chooser, and start it.
                        IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                                .newCreateFileActivityBuilder()
                                .setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                                .setInitialDriveContents(
                                        result.getDriveContents())
                                .build(mGoogleApiClient);
                        try {
                            startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender,
                                    REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR, null, 0, 0, 0);
                        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Failed to launch file chooser.");
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

[image]

Please help me

Comment: Make sure you have updated your sdk with latest apis.

Comment: What i understood by your quesion is you have problem in adding google play services lib project to your project ? if yes just check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22283550/error-in-adding-google-play-services-as-reference-library-in-eclipse

Comment: Drive.DriveApi.newContents(mGoogleApiClient)
                 .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ContentsResult>() {
                   @Override
                      public void onResult(ContentsResult result) {  }  use this one

Comment: Thanks for comment bro....but you are little bit late i have already done this after waisting ma 2 days...anyway thanks again

Comment: @KarthickM you can stil help me....i saved image successfully to google drive but.. m not able to get return image url(thumbnail url) of uploaded image....can you help me for doing this..

Comment: @DineshSpartacus I dont know that one,i am also strucking how to upload file to gdrive